# Array copy wants to modify source

Tags: arrays, copy, dafny

In the following code that copies a slice of an array into another one, the loop invariant that tells that the source array is preserved does not validate.

This is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46145269/3478605) and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34054804/3478605), but I have not found anything that works in this case yet.

```
method copy
  (a: array<int>, a0: nat,
  b: array<int>, b0: nat,
  len: nat)
  requires a != null && b != null
  requires a0 + len <= a.Length
  requires b0 + len <= b.Length
  modifies b
{
  var i := 0;
  while i < len
    decreases len - i
    invariant i <= len
    invariant a[..] == old(a[..])
  {
    b[b0 + i] := a[a0 + i];
    i := i + 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a precondition that `a != b`. Otherwise, if `a` and `b` are aliased, then the method might indeed modify `a`.